# how does bitcoind functions in bitcoin exchange model?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, address-generation, mycelium-wallet

i mean exchange allows every users a unique BTC deposit address

different users sends btc to different addresses but BTC endsup in same wallet

can i create multiple receiving address by bitcoind (getnewaddress)  or i will have to use HD wallet for that for our users (we are building lotto system on bitcoin)

Comment: If your project is sufficiently developed it would be great to see it published on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

A wallet is not the same as an address. A wallet is a collection of addresses. Wallets usually also contain the private keys for the addresses and any relevant transactions.

You can get as many addresses from `bitcoind` as you want with `getnewaddress` and they will all be part of the same wallet. Any coins sent to those addresses will be part of your wallet.

Also, Bitcoin Core is an HD wallet, but there is no need for you to have an HD wallet to do what you want. HD wallets are only relevant for backups.

Comment: we are working on project like an exchange its a lotto system plus lotto trading people can trade their lotto before declaration day,i wants to know if all coins will be part of our system wallet then there will be too many private keys for users right? if yes then how we can get regular backups of users private keys and public keys if they wants their private keys back

Comment: The private keys are your private keys, not the users private keys. They are part of your site's wallet. The user should never be giving you any private keys, nor should you be giving users any private keys. They are depositing money into your website; the money is yours.

Comment: Ok,thanks a lot .one more question : are you open for consultation we can pay for that by d way because i have at least 6 questions so i will need much help of your knowledge